# ISDATE not validating correct date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have few values in one of the column as below:

```
C_Date - Varchar(10)
00030503
10030503
```

when i use ISDATE function on this column, it is retruning as valid date (i.e. 1).
How can i ensure that ISDATE returns 0.?

```
Declare @c_date varchar(10)
Set @c_date =00030503
select case when ISDATE(@c_date)=0 then 'invalid' else 'valid' end
```

Can you please correct me?

When i apply same condition on a column from table, it is not working. It is giving me as valid date.
for Ex. i have a date with 080203, for which i am expecting invlid result, it is working with above query but when i put same on column from a table, it is giving Valid result.

Comment: @jpw do they? how do you interprete the 1st one -> `00030503`?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK My bad, forgot that the datetime range starts on 1753-01-01 unlike date that starts from  0001-01-01. I would interpret 00030503 as May 3rd year 3, but I know MSSQL doesn't.

Comment: I just copy and pasted the query you posted and get `invalid` as result

Comment: When i apply same condition on a column from table, it is not working. It is giving me as valid date.
for Ex. i have a date with 080203, for which i am expecting invlid result, it is working with above query but when i put same on column from a table, it is giving Valid result.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347%28SQL.105%29.aspx#SessionSettingDependencies);

> The return value of ISDATE depends on the settings set by SET
>   DATEFORMAT,  SET LANGUAGE and default language option.

If we explicitly set DateFormat to mdy then it will validate true to all dates in this format;

```
SET DATEFORMAT mdy;
```

So in your case, I guess you should precise the date format you want to compare your dates. I just tested the query you posted above and getting 'invalid' as result, as required.

Comment: +1. Even better: in the future, let's not store potential date information in a varchar column, mkay?